# Grouping by nested unique values

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, duplicates, unique

I have a matrix A in Matlab:

```
A = [176  5406  1  4  7903;
     155  5406  1  5  7903;
     122  5407  0  4  7903;
     140  5407  0  5  7904;
     130  5407  0  3  7904];
```

Just for information - the second column is a user ID, while the fourth column is a time. So `5406` is one user and `5407` is another user. Both of these users have some information stored in the first column and the 4th column which I am interested in accessing.

So basically what I want to do is:

1. For each user take the median of their values in the first column. I have written code (below) that works for this.
2. If there are two equal "time" values in column 5 for each user then I want to average the values in column 4. So like for user `5406` the time values are both `7903`, I want to the average of values in column 4 - i.e. the average of `4` and `5` to end up with one value (`4.5`).

But for example for the next user `5407` I will have two final values - one will be the average of 5 and 3 (because `7904` is repeated) and one will be 4 (because `7903` is not repeated).

I am a bit confused about how to do this, I know there needs to be an `if` statement of some sort, but I've been stuck on it for ages. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Code for the first part:

```
u=unique(A(:,2));
for i=1:size(u,1)
    M=find(A(i,2)==u(i));
    med(i)=median(A(M,1));
end
```

Comment: I'd use logical indexing, for example, for the first thing you want to do you can use: `median(A((A(:,2)==5406),1))` for the first user, etc...

Comment: I have just made the matrix smaller for the purpose of this question but I have around 20,000 users and I can't list each one out...

Comment: but you can loop over `u` that is written in the example... just replave the value 5406 with `u(i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run `unique` for the time values of each user (within the loop) and do a similar sub loop to collect the mean of unique timestamp for that user.

But here I think it's neater to use `accumarray`. In first example below, I've modified your code just a bit.

```
% Get unique
[user, ~, userIdx] = unique(A(:,2));
nUser = numel(user);

% Allocate container for result
med = zeros(nUser,1);
men = cell(nUser,1); % <-- Need a cell since length of result could vary

for i = 1:nUser
    % Median of col #1
    med(i) = median(A(userIdx == i, 1));

    % Mean of col #4 for unique times
    [~, ~, timeIdx] = unique(A(userIdx == i, 5));
    men{i} = accumarray(timeIdx, A(userIdx == i, 4), [], @mean);
end
```

Result:

```
>> med =
        165.5
          130

>> celldisp(men)
men{1} =
          4.5
men{2} =
          4
          4
```

---

To squeeze it a bit more, you could take unique time for entire `A` and use `accumarray` for both

```
[~, ~, userIdx] = unique(A(:,2));
[~, ~, timeIdx] = unique(A(:,5));

med = accumarray(userIdx, A(:,1), [], @median);
men = accumarray([userIdx timeIdx], A(:,4), [], @mean, NaN);
```

This gives `men` not as a cell but a matrix. Therefore the blank spaces has to be filled (here I choose `NaN` since 0 could be a result of `@mean`).

```
men =
          4.5          NaN
            4            4
```

If you want it as a cell without `NaN` you could just loop over the rows and pick non-NaN values, or place only the `men` calculation in the loop, or any other way...

If you are sure that column 4 of `A` doesn't contain any negative or zero numbers (mean value should never risk being 0), you could collect the result of `men` as a sparse matrix instead

```
men = accumarray([userIdx timeIdx], A(:,4), [], @mean, 0, true);
men =
   (1,1)             4.5
   (2,1)               4
   (2,2)               4
```

Answer (score 0):

I got another solution for your task without using any loops:

**Median values.**

```
u=unique(A(:,2));
umedians = arrayfun( @(x) median (A( A(:,2)==x, 1)), u);
```

Explanation:
find all unique users first. Then using `arrayfun` to find all data for current user and calculate `median` for every one of them.

**Average values of column 4.**

This task is a bit harder. We can go this way:

```
temp = arrayfun( @(x) unique(A ( A(:,2)==x,5 )), u, 'UniformOutput',false);
result = cellfun( @(y,z) arrayfun( @(x) mean( A( A(:,2) == u(z) & A(:,5) == x ,4) ), ... 
          y, 'UniformOutput',false), temp , num2cell( [1:size(u,1)]'), 'UniformOutput',false)
```

Explanation: first of all lets find all unique times for each users. Save it to cell array `temp`. Now we need for each cell find the same times and calculate mean. So lets use `cellfun` to made it for each cell of `temp` and use `arrayfun` into it to calculate `mean`.

Hope it helps!